# Pass along global variable to class

Tags: c#, global-variables

I am trying to pass a string to a public class (customPanel).

But the `"teststring"` is never passed on and written to the `testfile.txt`?
The `testfile.txt` writes an empty string.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customPanel cp = new customPanel();
    cp.getinfo = "teststring";
}

public class customPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    public String getinfo { get; set; }
    public customPanel() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        String gi = getinfo;

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:/folder1/testfile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
        writer.WriteLine(gi); writer.Close(); fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: InitializeComponent is called before getinfo string initialization (because it is called in the constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you’re having is happening because of the order of execution of your code.

Basically when you call `new customPanel()`, that’s when the constructor method `controlPanel()` is going to be called. So when you set the `getInfo` value, your `InitializeComponent()` method was already called.

Without knowing better about your context, the easy solution would be to pass the string as a parameter to your constructor. Basically switch `controlPanel()` to receive a `string variableName` as a parameter, like this `controlPanel(string variableName)`and then before calling `InitializeComponent();` set the value of the property with a `this.getInfo = variableName;`.

Let me know if this helped!

Take care.

Comment: Yes Felippe, that worked as you mentioned. The `InitializeComponent()` was called before as you said. So I did it exactly as you said and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Andreas glad it helped! Take care